# how to scan a text file with fscanf using delimiters?

Tags: c, text, delimiter, scanf

So this is how the text in the file looks like:

```
    locked y
    locked n
    position 90
    position 2
    audio-language "english"
    audio-language "spanish"
```

each text file contains only one kind of the settings shown above, the difference is the option (y or n, 1 to 999, "english" "spanish" "whatever else") it has 4 white spaces in front and a new line at the end of each line, so I need a fscanf that will extract the parameter in a char array string, but I cant seem to understand how to use the delimiters right. I have to make a program that can scan that file and print the different settings and how many times they are found in the file for example:

```
audio-language is found with setting: "spanish" 40 times

audio-language is found with setting: "english" 78 times
```

***Than you all for your answers! Here i can show you how I made it work:***

1 - First you use a funcion ( that I found on the internet ) that eliminates the white spaces in front of the settings:

```
char* ltrim(char* s) 
{
    char* newstart = s;

  while (isspace( *newstart)) {
    ++newstart;
   }

   // newstart points to first non-whitespace char (which might be '\0')
   memmove( s, newstart, strlen( newstart) + 1); // don't forget to move the '\0' terminator

return s;
 }
```

2 - Then fscanf has no problem getting the line right:

```
while(!feof(fpoo)) {
    fscanf(fpoo,"%s %[^\n]",&first, &sec);
```

3 - Then you compare the ones fscanf got with the ones the user entered

That's it, apparently the whole problem with **fscanf** was because of the white spaces in front of every line.

Comment: Please **show** your try...

Comment: I think it will be solved by `strtok`

Comment: For a C solution, I recommend using [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to get each line, and then do `sscanf` to get the key and the value. If the value is supposed to be numerical, use e.g. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) after the scanning to convert it. Use `strcmp` on the key to know what key it is.

Comment: For C++, use e.g. [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) for the actual parsing of the line. Store key and counters in an [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: If you actually want to *store* the values for later retrieval, in C++ you could use [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap) instead.

Comment: And as a last advice, please pick *one* language for your problems in the future. Even though C and C++ are related, they are still different and the solutions in each language will be very different.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes sorry about that it was a mistake.

Comment: Anyway thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled this code and tested it. Works perfectly. You can test it too :)

```
int main()
{
    int bytes_read = 0, english_count = 0, spanish_count = 0;
    char file_buffer[256], setting[127], option[32], fileName[32] = "FileName.txt";
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen("FileName.txt", "rb")) <=0)
    {
       printf("Unable to open the File\n");
    }
    //rewind(fp);
    while(fgets (file_buffer, 50, fp))
    {
       sscanf(file_buffer,"%s %s",setting,option);
       printf("Setting: ");
       printf("%s",setting);
       printf("\nOption: ");
       printf("%s",option);
       printf("\n\n");
       if(memcmp(setting,"audio-language",14) == 0)
       {
           if(memcmp(option,"english",7) == 0)
           {
               english_count = english_count+1;
           }
           if(memcmp(option,"spanish",7) == 0)
           {
               spanish_count = spanish_count+1;
           }
       }
           //you can add more checks here.
      }
    printf("\naudio-language is found with setting: english ");
    printf("%d",english_count);
    printf("\naudio-language is found with setting: spanish ");
    printf("%d",spanish_count);
    printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, that would work perfectly, but I have to make it work for all possible languages and not only, but all kind of other settings and if i do it that way its gonna be one long long program.

Answer (score 1):

You can first read in the strings as:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",buffer)
```

Now you can use the tokenizer in C to get the value of the language by using **strtok**

```
char *token="\n";
token = strtok(line, token);
```

Now token will contain all the split words, which you can compare with strcmp with the languages possible and maintain a count

Comment: can I somehow ignore the first 4 white spaces and the first string and store only the second string witch can be a word or a number and all that only using the delimiters in scanf without using the strtok ?

Comment: s/`"%[^\n]s"`/`"%[^\n]"`/... and `fscanf` doesn't use that kind of regular expression. Which manual did you read?

Comment: @AakashAnuj : `scanf("%[^\n]s",buffer)`OK but what if buffer is not an array of chars but a single float which I need to read as a float?

Answer (score 0):

check the algorithm and you have to code

1. Read the file line by line e,g say 1024 byte at a time.
2. Then scan for the line you want e.g in your case  audio-language "english" or  audio-language "spanish".
3. Get the string for language type
4. Then count how many times you found this line.

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have done 1. and 2. so far, but i have troubles doing 3. and 4. because there are many different options not only english or spanish there might be 50 different languages or positions from 1 to 999, and I just have no idea how to count and print them, I can print them either on the screen or frpintf in a file.

Comment: It is very simple if the format of the line is "case audio-language "english"".Just search for first " symbol by using any standard function.e,g strstr() for " symbol alone and then if found you can get the the pointer to the starting of that string (strstr() returns)then read upto next " symbol and then you can get the language type.

Comment: the thing is that i have to make it work with all the different options too and some of them don't have "" like = locked y or position 100. I don't know maybe I have to type separate code for all of the cases.

Comment: yes,but what you asked is you need to know regarding the languages and its occurrence  so I have told to scan only the line containing language option.

Answer (score 0):

The people in your comments are right. You really should've shown us your try. If this is homework, then you can't cheat because your lecturers could bust you with a simple google search. It's wasteful to expect us to guess your understanding here and cover content that you've already covered, so show us what you've done.

`qsort`, `bsearch` and `strcmp` provide an easy, relatively efficient sort & search mechanism for anything that starts with a string (eg. string-prefixed structs). A whitespace in the format string tells `fscanf` to consume as much whitespace as possible. `fscanf` returns a value indicating modes of success and failure, meaning you don't necessarily need to read each line into an array of chars to test whether or not the input matches a specific format. However, you do need to take care in designing the file so that none of the commands have common prefixes to other commands. In this case, you're safe.

Here's my attempt. Happy debugging :)

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct language_table { char language[64]; size_t count; };
struct language_table *parse(FILE *f, size_t *s);

int main(void) {
    size_t s;
    struct language_table *t = parse(stdin, &s);

    while (s-- > 0) {
        printf("audio-language is found with setting: %s %zu times\n", t[s].language, t[s].count);
    }

    free(t);
}

struct language_table *parse(FILE *f, size_t *s) {
    char locked, language[64];
    unsigned int position;

    int c = 0;

    struct language_table *table = NULL, *entry;
    size_t size = 0;

    do {
        if (fscanf(f, " locked %c", &locked) == 1 && strchr("ynYN", locked)) {
            /* XXX: Do something with locked. */
        }
        else if (fscanf(f, " position %u", &position) == 1) {
            /* XXX: Do something with position. */
        }
        else if (fscanf(f, " audio-language %63s", language) == 1) {
            /* search for the language in table. */
            entry = bsearch(language, table, size, sizeof *table, strcmp);

            /* insert the language if it's not found. */
            if (entry == NULL) {
                if ((size & (size + 1)) == 0) {
                    void *new = realloc(table, (size * 2 + 1) * sizeof *table);
                    if (new == NULL) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate new entry for %s\n", language);
                        free(table);
                        return NULL;
                    }
                    table = new;
                }

                entry = table + size++;
                strcpy(entry->language, language);
                entry->count = 0;

                /* sort & search */
                qsort(table, size, sizeof *table, strcmp);
                entry = bsearch(language, table, size, sizeof *table, strcmp);
            }

            entry->count++;
        }
        else {
            /* consume an invalid line */
            do {
                c = fgetc(f);
            } while (c >= 0 && c != '\n');
        }
    } while (c >= 0);

    *s = size;
    return table;
}
```